# Using MySQL unique index with good atomicity without raising errors

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique, atomic

I have this table:

```
User
    id INT PK
    login VARCHAR UNIQUE
```

I want to know the best way to handle UNIQUE index insertion  (ex: new user creation)

1) I can simply INSERT and when a "duplicate entry is raised" and I catch the exception and handle it in the application

=> I'm not sure this is the best solution to do that

2) I can SELECT ... WHERE login = ... then INSERT when no record found or display an error if the select found something

=> This is not atomic, an insert can happen between SELECT and INSERT

3) I can start a transaction, SELECT FOR UPDATE, INSERT then COMMIT when no records found or ROLLBACK and display an error if the user already exists

=> This simply won't work since MySQL doesn't lock no existing lines... So it will certainly result in a deadlock

So what is the best way to handle this very simple study case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an

```
INSERT IGNORE ...
```

[MySQL manual INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)

Or

```
REPLACE ...
```

[MySQL manual REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html)

Comment: I think I could use ON DUPLICATE KEY too, but I 'm really curious if there is a solution to LOOK UP for an existing key instead of trying to insert and see what is happening.

Comment: @nemenems Why would you want that? It's just an extra query your server has to handle. Also the ON DUPLICATE KEY thing. It's basically an UPDATE if the row already exists. So do this only if other columns in the row have changed. Otherwise spare yourself the extra operation your server has to handle. And don't forget, you also get rid of the atomic problem.

Comment: Understood but the REPLACE or is just worst than ON DUPLICATE KEY since it will rewrite in both case the row. I think catching the error while INSERTING seems to be the only acceptable solution

Comment: @nemenems I'd go with INSERT IGNORE too

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have two options:

1) Use [Lock Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) and `SELECT` then `Insert`. Locking the table will ensure you don't end up with a race condition.

2) If you're concerned about the table lock, you can do the first option that you listed: `INSERT` or better yet, `INSERT IGNORE`. If you use `INSERT IGNORE` then the duplicate key exception will instead be returned as a warning.

Personally, I'd try the table lock and see if it works. Your `SELECT` statement should run quickly since it has a unique key, so I wouldn't worry about locks slowing you down too much.

Comment: Lock table is definitively not the good solution since a table lock is really heavy. My example is a study case. Imagine the same problematic for write intensive database